# Strange behaviour in AngularJS Getting Redirected if parameter is passed in url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

Here is my JS

```
.when('/showprofile/:UserID', {
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/showprofile.php',
                    controller: 'ShowOrderController',
                  })
```

and in the last line i have

```
app.controller('ShowOrderController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.UserID = $routeParams.UserID;
});
```

Here's the link i am dealing with

`localhost/project/#/showprofile/18`

Whenever i enter this link, i am getting redirected to

`localhost/project/#/showprofile/:UserID`

**Why it is redirected ? What is the mistake i am doing ?**

Comment: question isn't clear enough. what is 18 here userId or orderId redirected url includes params as :UserID ?

Comment: @atinder  18 is just the parameter in the url , that i wanted to pass to the view

Comment: Do you have any error in your console?

Comment: No error, but after the below answerer's update i have `TypeError: Cannot read property '$$route' of undefined` error

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing the parameter in a wrong way. **Instead of:**

```
.when('/showprofile/:UserID'
```

**try this:**

```
.when('/showprofile/user=:UserID'
```

You have to assign the **value** 'UserID' to be passed to a **parameter**, say 'user'.

The **final url** will be like this:

```
localhost/project/#/showprofile/user=:UserID
```

Comment: I am getting this error **TypeError: Cannot read property '$$route' of undefined** when i try your method..

Comment: I have edited the answer. Try that and let me know if it works.

Comment: maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196330/angularjs-routing-typeerror-cannot-read-property-path-of-undefined

Answer (score 0):

i have tried similar example and it worked.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when("/:firstName/:middleName/:lastName",
    {
      templateUrl: "app.html",
      controller: "AppCtrl",
      controllerAs: "app"
    }
  );
})

.controller('AppCtrl', function($routeParams) {
  this.message = $routeParams.firstName + " " + $routeParams.middleName + " " + $routeParams.lastName;
});
```

compare it with your code if something is wrong.

Comment: i can't find any changes.. still it is redirecting.. (